Flask session with timeout that terminates on browser close
I have two requirements for my Flask session (that I use to keep user information after a successful SAML login):
(1) The session must time out after 60 minutes.
(2) The session must terminate on browser close
I know that I can achieve the session timeout as follows:
session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)

But doing that also leads to the session not terminating on browser close since we are setting session.permanent to True.
Is there a way to achieve both conditions without "hacks" like this that detect browser close events in JavaScript?

Flask (and any other web server) can't get automatically information when user closed browser (because HTTP doesn't keep connection and it can't get information when socket is closed). It would need to use some JavaScript to send message to server when user close web page or browser.

eventually page whould need JavaScript to delete in browser cookies with session ID - and next time browser will not have ID to active session.

But if I set sesion.permanent to False, the session does get terminated on browser close (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.session.permanent). So, why can I not set session.permanent to False and ALSO specify a timeout?

because browsers keeps it in cookies which allow for terminate on browser close (when cookies has empty expire-date) or terminate after some time (when  cookies has expire-date with date and time) but they don't allow for both. I think it would need to change flask and it should set session.permanent = False (and it will terminate on browser close) and flask should check cookies in every request and compare with value in database (or in some file) and delete cookies when it is expired (and send page with login form).

Thank you @furas for making clear that this is a fundamental limitation in the way browsers handle cookies. I was not ware of the distinction between session and permanent cookies. I found this article helpful in explaining the two. The security requirements for my application require both conditions, so I will implement a JavaScript solution.
